# angular ng-class add class to all except current

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

i have a checkbox inside a table when i check one checkbox i want to add disabled class to all other i tried to achieve this using ng-class

```
<td scope="row">
<input 
    type="checkbox"
    id="{{$index}}"
    ng-class="{disabled: $index != currentid}"      
    ng-click="showOptions($event,'$index')" />
</td>
```

inside controller

```
$scope.showOptions=function($event,id){
    if($event.target.checked){    
        $scope.btns = true;
        $scope.details_tab = true;
        $scope.currentid = id;
    } 
    else {
        $scope.btns = false;
        $scope.details_tab = false;
    }
};
```

but using this when the page loads all checkboxes have disabled class.

Comment: Why is `$index` a string? ==>  `showOptions($event,'$index')`.  Shouldn't that be `showOptions($event,$index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but using this when the page loads all checkboxes have disabled class.

This is due to the fact that on page load, all $index values are different than currentid, which you only set after a click.

You need to make sure you have a checked checkbox:

```
$scope.showOptions = function ($event, id) {
    if ($event.target.checked) {
        $scope.btns = true;
        $scope.details_tab = true;
        $scope.currentid = id;
        $scope.disableCheckboxes = true; //checking a checkbox
    } else {
        $scope.btns = false;
        $scope.details_tab = false;
        $scope.disableCheckboxes = false; //unchecking a checked checkbox
    }
};
```

And in HTML you need to consider that inside your `ng-click` (also you don't need the quotes on the `$index` as others have said):

```
<td scope="row">
<input 
    type="checkbox"
    id="{{$index}}"
    ng-class="{disabled: disableCheckboxes && $index != currentid}"      
    ng-click="showOptions($event,$index)" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `showOptions`, `$index` doesn't need to be the string with value `'$index'`.  It needs to be the value `$index`:

```
<td scope="row">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="{{$index}}" 
           ng-class="{disabled: $index != currentid}" 
           ng-click="showOptions($event, $index)"/>
</td>
```

Otherwise, you will be comparing the literal value `$index` with an integer index (ex. `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a validation on currentid. Add the class only if there is something in 'currentid' AND $index is not currentid. 
Now you can set currentid to undefined on page load.

```
<td scope="row"><input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}" ng-class="{disabled: $index != currentid && currentid}" ng-click="showOptions($event,'$index')"></td>
```